# synchronize multiple modules with intelIj

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-15

I'm wondering if we can work with intelij like we work with eclipse workspace:

In fact , we have a project with multiple dependent modules ( more than 50 modules ), with eclipse I know that we have the principl of workspace so if for example we update a commun module, all other modules which depend on this commun module will be updated ( no need to do : mvn install to update with commun module modification ).

Can we do that with intelij?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can work same like workspace in eclipse. If you want to simulate the Eclipse workflow, you should create an empty project (~ workspace) first:

New Project > Empty Project

Now you can create separate modules  to be shown exactly like you want:

Select the top-level directory in the Project tool window and press Alt+Insert or select New | Module from the context menu.

The New Module wizard opens.

From the list on the left, select a module type. Name the new module.

If you want to get the detailed instructions . How to work with modules in intelliJ . It is all shown step by step and clearly on the below link :)

[Working with modules in INtelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#multimodule-projects)

Comment: does it synchronize the builds ?  , if I modify a common module , will I be obliged to do : mvn install on the other modules ?

Comment: Yes if the modules are connected the changes are synchronised over the whole project as it is set to reload on external changes by default . However, you can go to project settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Build tools and set it to any changes of you want it to reload the project on any changes forcefully :)